# How to get item index appropriately using React 16.8 Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am practicing a todo list project using React 16 Hooks. However, I found it's hard to get the index using inside map() function like this:

Parent Todo Component:

```
const Todo = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { list } = useSelector(state => state.todoReducer.toJS());
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    function handleOnchange (e) {
        setValue(e.target.value)
    }

    function handleAddItem() {
        actionCreators.addItem(dispatch, value);
        setValue('');
    }

    function handleRemoveItem(index) {
        // if use handleChecked(index) will trigger  handleItemChecked and printed all //indexes everytime
        actionCreators.removeItem(dispatch, value);
    }

    function handleItemChecked(index) {
        console.log(index)
    }

    return (
        <>
          <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleOnchange} />
          <button onClick={handleAddItem}>+</button>
          <List items={list} handleClick={handleRemoveItem} isCompeted={false} handleChecked={handleItemChecked}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Child Component:

```
    const List = ({items, handleClick, isCompleted, handleChecked}) => {
   return (
       <ListWrapper>
         {items && items.length > 0 && items.map((item, index) => {
             return (
                 <ListWrapper.item key={`${item}${new Date()}${Math.random()}`}>
                 {/* if like this: onClick={handleChecked(index)} will cause the issue */}
                    {/* <li>{item}<input type="checkbox" onClick={handleChecked(index)}/></li> */}
                    <li>{item}<input type="checkbox" name={index} onClick={e => handleChecked(e.target.name)}/></li>
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>-</button>
                 </ListWrapper.item>
            );
         })}
       </ListWrapper>
   )
}
```

I found if in the child component: List, if I need to get the index of item, I have to assign name={index} . If using handleChecked(index) directly, will cause rendering many times issue in its parent component(Todo). Is any better way to handle this case? Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: `onClick={() => handleChecked(index)}`? You want to provide something to get called, not to immediately call it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Looks lie it not because of Hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as commented by jonrsharpe:

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>-</button>
```

here's 2 known methods to fix it:

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>-</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={handleClick.bind(this, index)}>-</button>
```

read about that: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

hope helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Both works ! I thought this only works for Class based component